# Countdown timer starts at specified time and date, I need it to use time and date on android phone

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

I am trying to get this countdown to count down to the day of an event in days/hours/minutes/seconds. I need to change this code to use the current android phone time and date at start up to show remaining time left according to what time and date your phone shows. Currently the start time and date is set by me, and every time I install and run the app on emulator it shows 34 days so if I install and run it tomorrow it wont show 33 days but 34 days again.. I cannot find any questions with a helpful answer and I have looked several places over the past couple days. Here is my event activity java and I am using TextView in relative layout.

```
extends Activity {

Button button01;
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
TextView mTextView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_activity);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm");
    Date a = null, b = null;
    try {
        a = sdf.parse("24-02-2014, 14:30");
        b = sdf.parse("06-01-2014, 02:04");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(a.getTime() - b.getTime(), 1000) {
        StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
            //mTextView.setText("Times Up!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setLength(0);
             // Use days if appropriate
            if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                long count = millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
                if(count > 1)
                    time.append(count).append(" days, ");
                else
                    time.append(count).append(" day, ");

                millisUntilFinished %= DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
            }

                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS) {
                    long count2 = millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
                    if(count2 > 1)
                        time.append(count2).append(" hours, ");
                    else
                        time.append(count2).append(" hour, ");

                    millisUntilFinished %= DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
            }
                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS) {
                    long count3 = millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
                    if(count3 > 1)
                        time.append(count3).append(" minutes, ");
                    else
                        time.append(count3).append(" minute, ");

                    millisUntilFinished %= DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
                }

            time.append(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000d)));
            mTextView.setText(time.toString());
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Please help, how can I get this to update current time instead of adding start day and time myself! It doesn't show the correct start time when I run the emulator because of the time it takes me to run it. Thanks

-KG

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class MainActivityCalDate extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")       
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.cal_date);

            TextView tv1;

            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);      


            SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            java.util.Date d = null;
            java.util.Date d1 = null;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            try {
                    d = dfDate.parse("13/02/2014 ");
                    d1 = dfDate.parse(dfDate.format(cal.getTime()));//Returns 15/10/2012
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            int diffInDays = (int) ((d.getTime() - d1.getTime())/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            System.out.println(diffInDays);
            tv1.setText(""+diffInDays);
        }

    }
```

It will work. You change the date from emulator Date and Time settings and restart the Activity it will show updated result from the current day. If you have any query then ask me.

Comment: I am getting errors saying these imports aren't used 'import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException; import java.util.Date;'

Comment: Also SimpleDateFormat shows this error 'Description Resource Path Location Type
To get local formatting use getDateInstance(), getDateTimeInstance(), or getTimeInstance(), or use new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale) with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates. Line 27 Android Lint Problem'

Comment: Please remove first your previous import fields and add my import field. It's nothing else it's just clashes with two different import. SimpleDateFormat does not show error it's just show yellow alert message. But it does not hamper the code.

Comment: I have edited for SimpleDateFormat Alert . Now it will not show any alert.

Comment: It wont run for me, I tried the suppresslint,double checked imports, it says no problems but does not run on emulator. The source code I posted runs like it should but it starts on ("06-01-2014, 02:04") and I want it to start instead at the current time everytime... so five days later when I open the app it shows the time is less 5days because 5days have passed.. is this possible? :/

Comment: @user3167632 please create a fresh activity and simply paste my code on it, and run this activity. because before I gave you this code I have run this code several times. If you want full source code, then please give me your email id I will send you. Because it is workable code dude

Comment: Thank you! I just had to add @SuppressWarnings("unused") for some imports. It works perfect, thanks!